# React Native with Redux Action not passing data to reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have a problem in which action is not passing data to the reducer.
I re-render by change any things use hot reloading. it is receive data and try again to reload all the app. the same issue.

### Reducer file

```js
const initialState = {
  categories: null,
  error: '',
  isLoading: false,
};

const CategoriesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(state.categories);
  switch (action.type) {
    case CATEGORIES_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case CATEGORIES_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default CategoriesReducer;
```

### Action file

I use Axios for fetch data and redux-thunk

```js
const onCategoriesActionState = () => {
  return {
    type: CATEGORIES_STATE,
  };
};

const onCategoriesActionSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
};

const onCategoriesActionFailed = (error) => {
  return {
    type: CATEGORIES_FAILED,
    error,
  };
};

const CategoriesAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(onCategoriesActionState());
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${Api}categories`);
      dispatch(onCategoriesActionSuccess(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(onCategoriesActionFailed(error));
    }
  };
};

export default CategoriesAction;
```

### Call in Screen

```js
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    if (categoriesReducer !== null) {
      setCategories(categoriesReducer);
    }
  }, [])
);
React.useEffect(() => {
  categoriesAction();
}, []);
```

anyone to help me to find where is the problem in my code

Comment: Have you debugged or used browser networking output tools?  For instance to see what (if anything) is coming back at: `const {data} = await axios.get(`${Api}categories`);`

Comment: Response data from API

Comment: Maybe check to see if `const {data} = await axios.get(${Api}categories)` should be `const data = await axios.get(${Api}categories)`

Comment: If I use it. I will use await two times like : const data = await axios.get(${Api}categories); const result = await data.data

Comment: I wouldn't think you would need to use await 2x.  const data = await axios.get(); const result = data.data;  Besides, using data as a const here is confusing.  I'd do const response = await axios.get();  const categories = response.data ?? {};

Comment: The same problems not passing

Comment: But if I change any thing in screen . The data is passing

Comment: Hmm, also React documentation says that useFocusEffect is analogous to useEffect hook, so I'm not sure why you have useEffect nested within the useFocusEffect, this doesn't look right to me.  Additionally, the effect will run whenever the dependencies passed to React.useCallback change, i.e. it'll run on initial render (if the screen is focused) as well as on subsequent renders if the dependencies have changed. If you don't wrap your effect in React.useCallback, the effect will run every render if the screen is focused.  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a redux action with side effects, in order to run that you'll need to dispatch it from your component

- First get the dispatch object from your props or use the dispatch hook then
  dispatch your action.
- Without dispatching your action from your component Redux has no way
  to find out about your action or event therefore without wrapping
  your action inside dispatch function you are only calling a simple
  function.
- NOTE: to dispatch async action and side effects you'll need to use [Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or
  [Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) middleware

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(categoriesAction());
}, []);
```

Comment: I use thunk. data is not a problem. I have problem in useEffect did not re-render state.

Comment: I know you forgot to call dispatch on useEffect
instead of calling categoriesAction(); call dispatch(categoriesAction()) inside useEffect

Comment: I use connect bottom in my file: const mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{
    return {
        productsReducer: state.productsReducer.products,
        isLoading: state.productsReducer.isLoading,
        categoriesReducer: state.categoriesReducer.categories,
        isLoadingCategories: state.categoriesReducer.isLoading,
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
    return {
        productsAction: () => dispatch(ProductsAction()),
        categoriesAction: () => dispatch(CategoriesAction()),
    }
}

Comment: You can see my code for this screen by this link: https://snack.expo.dev/@younisabuzayed/069eed

Comment: Thanks for response. I solved problem: useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    if (categoriesReducer !== null) {
      setCategories(categoriesReducer);
    }
  }, [categoriesReducer, categories]);

Comment: Glad to hear that, Thanks